# How to set TRUSTWORTHY for every instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, instance

My database uses external C++ libraries for some calculations. 
As [said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.trustworthy.aspx) `TRUSTWORTHY` indicates whether the instance trusts database.

Is it possible to set it for every instance connected to database without doing it manually.

`ALTER DATABASE db_lib  SET TRUSTWORTHY ON`

Comment: The question is: why do you need trustworthy on your databases? It's a security hole that you should understand before blindly enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible as of SQL Server 2014. You'll have to find a way to automate this. Add this to the process that you use to add a new database.

Comment: Are any system event for resolving it with trigger?